# groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.io.File(File)

Tags: file, groovy, constructor

I've been working with Groovy and Grails for a few weeks now.

I've just had a problem that any File creation command such as below:

```
void validate(FileToValidate) {
        try {
            DefaultImmutableModuleIdentifierFactory moduleIdentifierFactory = new DefaultImmutableModuleIdentifierFactory()
            def moduleDescriptorConverter = new IvyModuleDescriptorConverter(moduleIdentifierFactory)
            def metadataFactory = new IvyMutableModuleMetadataFactory(moduleIdentifierFactory,null)
            def repository = new DefaultExternalResourceRepository("repo", null, null, null, null, null,null)
            def files =  new java.io.File(FileToValidate)
            URI uri = files.toURI()
            def name = new ExternalResourceName(uri)
            def parser = new IvyXmlModuleDescriptorParser(moduleDescriptorConverter, moduleIdentifierFactory,repository.resource(name ,true), metadataFactory)
            DescriptorParseContext ivySettings = null //new DisconnectedDescriptorParseContext();
            parser.parseMetaData(ivySettings, FileToValidate, true);

        } catch (MetaDataParseException e) {
            throw new GradleException("Invalid ivy descriptor file $FileToValidate", e);
        }
    }
```

I am getting below error:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.io.File(File)
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-class-in-java/

Answer (score 2):

in my case I had only path so had to create file on my own,
it helped:

```
new java.io.File(FileToValidate.toString())
```

as toString

> Returns the string representation of this path.

Comment: I had the same problem after upgrading Gradle to v7. Your fix worked for me, but in the end I was able to solve the problem by moving from `new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve(...)"])` in build.gradle (from Expo-Modules migration) to relative reference `"../../node_modules/.."` see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33641

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a `File` to `void validate(FileToValidate) {`

Then trying to create a new File out of it here

```
            def files =  new java.io.File(FileToValidate)
```

You don't need to do this...  Just use `FileToValidate`

As a side note, sticking to lower case initial letters for variables and arguments is advised, to avoid confusion, so

```
void validate(fileToValidate) {
```